# I want to Show a banner in iOS app when network not reachable and disable apps functionality until it is reachable again . Is it possible?

Tags: ios

I had created an iOS app which crashes when network is not reachable since data received is nil. Since I don't want to update all the parts of code accessing network , I just want to show a banner when internet is not reachable and temporarily disable all the parts of app so that it docent crashes .
I saw this feature in UBER app and so I was curious .
Can anyone help me in this matter ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most of the third party library outside used for networking use an Apple class called `Reachability`. [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) helps you to check if there is an internet connection before calling a web service or a network functionality in general. You can use in two ways:

1. test if connectivity is available before doing network operation
2. register as an observer to connectivity status changes

To do what you want to achieve just register the interesting classes as observers and once you get the notification check if the internet connection is available or not, doing the operation that you want: like alert the user, put an overlay over the interface to block any user operation until a the connection is available again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. The network can be there when a download starts and disappear while your call is executing. Even if you only start calls when Reachability tells you that the network is there, you can still get nil results. The only solution is: Fix your code so you don't crash.

Obviously you may feel free to tell the user that the network isn't there. You might also suggest to the user to check whether they have Airplane mode turned on or whether WiFi / 3G is turned off. But you can't rely on this to avoid getting connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple class and a demo project in order to track reachability changes in a block, so you can easily apply changes on your view controller's objects according to these changes https://github.com/PabloAlejandro/PA-reachability-blocks

In order to use it add 'ReachabilityBlocks.h' and 'ReachabilityBlocks.m' to your project and declare a strong instance of 'ReachabilityBlocks'. Then you can call 'listenReachabilityUpdates' instance method in order to start tracking changes.

In your view controller:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) ReachabilityBlocks * reachabilityBlocks;
@end
```

and then on 'viewDidLoad' (or whenever you prefer to start getting updates)

```
self.reachabilityBlocks = [ReachabilityBlocks new];
[self.reachabilityBlocks listenReachabilityUpdates:^(GCNetworkReachabilityStatus networkStatus) {

        switch (networkStatus) {
            case GCNetworkReachabilityStatusWiFi:
                self.label.text = @"WiFi";
                break;
            case GCNetworkReachabilityStatusWWAN:
                self.label.text = @"WWAN";
                break;
            case GCNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
                self.label.text = @"Not Reachable";
                break;
        }
    }];
```

I hope this helps.

Note: The class imports 'GCNetworkReachability' library, so don't forget to add it to your class, either manually or using Cocoapods